# R SaTScan package not producing expected output

Tags: r, satscan

I am using the rsatscan package to automate a spatial scan statistic analysis. I'm attempting to eliminate the need to use the gui.

I have been able to successfully create valid input files (geo,cas,prm); however, when I attempt to run the satscan function, no output is returned. Here is the code I'm running to set the parameters and run the analysis:

````
##reset parameters file 
invisible(ss.options(reset=TRUE))

##set SaTScan Parameters
ss.options(list(CaseFile="malawi.cas",PrecisionCaseTimes=0))
ss.options(list(PopulationFile="malawi.pop"))
ss.options(list(CoordinatesFile="malawi.geo"))
ss.options(list(PrecisionCaseTimes=3,
                AnalysisType=1,
                ModelType=0,
                TimeAggregationUnits=1,
                MaxSpatialSizeInDistanceFromCenter=20,
                CriteriaForReportingSecondaryClusters=0,
                ReportGiniClusters="n",
                OutputShapefiles="y",
                CoordinatesType=1,
                UseDistanceFromCenterOption="y",
                ScanAreas=1,
                GeographicalCoordinatesCheckType=1))


head(ss.options(),3)

##Write satscan parameter file
td = "~/Documents/RSaTScan"
write.ss.prm(td, "CountryRec")
write.cas(malawiCas, td, "CountryRec")
write.geo(malawiGeo, td, "CountryRec")
write.pop(malawiPop, td, "CountryRec")

##run satscan
malawiRec<-satscan(prmlocation=td,
                  prmfilename="CountryRec", 
                  sslocation = "SaTScan",ssbatchfilename = "SaTScanBatch64", cleanup=T, verbose=F)```
````

Comment: I've removed the "rstudio" tag because this is very unlikely to be anything to do with RStudio.

Comment: The `rsatscan` package was removed from CRAN last year https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsatscan/index.html - what version are you using and where did you get it from?

Comment: @spacedman I was able to download an archived version here [https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rsatscan]

Answer (score 0):

I've also been working with the archived version of rsatscan, and it has some idiosyncrasies because it's now quite a bit out of date. If you haven't already been able to solve this problem, there are a few things I can recommend:

1. Have you tried running in verbose mode? `satscan(..., verbose = TRUE)` If you're able to get an error message from that, it would be helpful to post here.
2. One of the biggest problems with `rsatscan` is that it's built for an earlier version of SaTScan. Since then, additional parameters have been added to SaTScan that `rsatscan` does not account for, and this can cause the call to `satscan()` to to fail. Been a bit since I ran into this issue personally, but IIRC it can happen *even if you aren't trying to use those newer parameters*. I got around this by writing a custom method that overrides what's included in `ssenv$.ss.params` with a new list of parameters that matches the latest version of SaTScan. It looks a bit like this:

```
    override_rsatscan_prms <- function() {
    
      # Generate the new (more up-to-date) list of SaTScan parameters:
      x = c("[Input]",
            ";case data filename",
            "CaseFile=",
            ";control data filename",
            "ControlFile=",
            ";time precision (0=None, 1=Year, 2=Month, 3=Day, 4=Generic)",
            "PrecisionCaseTimes=1",
            ";study period start date (YYYY/MM/DD)",
            "StartDate=2000/1/1",
            ";study period end date (YYYY/MM/DD)",
            "EndDate=2000/12/31",
            ";population data filename",
            "PopulationFile=",
            ";coordinate data filename",
            "CoordinatesFile=",
            ";use grid file? (y/n)",
            "UseGridFile=n",
            ";grid data filename",
            "GridFile=",
            ";coordinate type (0=Cartesian, 1=latitude/longitude)",
            "CoordinatesType=1",
            "",
            "[Analysis]",
            ";analysis type (1=Purely Spatial, 2=Purely Temporal, 3=Retrospective Space-Time, 4=Prospective Space-Time, 5=Spatial Variation in Temporal Trends, 6=Prospective Purely Temporal)",
            "AnalysisType=1",
            ";model type (0=Discrete Poisson, 1=Bernoulli, 2=Space-Time Permutation, 3=Ordinal, 4=Exponential, 5=Normal, 6=Continuous Poisson, 7=Multinomial)",

    # so on and so forth, for all other parameters, separated into groups like [Input] and [Analysis]...

            "[System]",
            ";system setting - do not modify",
            "Version=10.0.2",
            "")

    # Override the environment defaults set by `rsatscan` when the package is first loaded:
    ssenv$.ss.params.defaults = x
    ssenv$.ss.params = x

  }
```

Hope this is helpful! It's a bit frustrating— I feel that `rsatscan` remains the best IO tool to use SaTScan with R (at least from all the packages that I've seen), but it really needs some TLC... hopefully someone can take over maintaining it for future use, or it gets supplanted by something better soon.